# Gantt chart that automatically distributes hours across multiple concurrent tasks, and automatically rolls over unprogressed tasks

Tags: gantt

I'm not sure if a Gantt chart / Gantt software is the wrong tool for my use case, or I'm unaware of some technique / terminology.

Given (1) a set of tasks, (2) time estimated to complete each task, and (3) dependencies to other tasks, I want a view that shows when each task would be completed **if a single resource were allocated evenly among all tasks**.

Maybe easier to imagine: *"Roughly how much can be accomplished by September given a 1-person team?"*

So far I've played around with Teamweek and TeamGantt (advanced trial) with no luck. These seem to require manually assigning hours or tasks per day per resource, whereas I want that assignment done automatically, rolling over incomplete tasks (*e.g.* unexpected sick day) automatically as well, so that I always see a forecast of completion.

Are Gantt charts the wrong tool? Or is there some technique or term I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I think I found my answer through one of the related questions: [Project Management Gantt Tool makes All Tasks Concurrent](https://pm.stackexchange.com/a/26093/8423)
.

It looks like what I'm trying to do is **level resources** (in my case, a single resource).

It's [not available in TeamGantt](https://teamgantt.uservoice.com/forums/105753-general/suggestions/1562299-resource-leveling) for sure, and I don't believe in TeamWeek either.

As of June 29th, 2018, one of the commenters in that link states,

> I tested more than 30 project management software and [only] found [resource leveling] in Gantter and MS Project.

---

**Edit**

Much easier to research now that I've found the term "resource leveling."

[Wrike supposedly supports resource-leveling as "Workloads"](https://help.wrike.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115003260285-Effective-Resource-Allocation-within-Wrike), but it costs over $65/month to get Gantt charts (for 5 users), and then more to get the Resource integration that introduces Workloads. Microsoft Project, in comparison, currently costs $30/month/user. So, I guess it depends.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem properly:

I think you would get the result you expect if you treat your resource as a task - I think most software would then handle it properly.

Comment: Could you say a little more? I'm sorry but I don't understand.